# Making a dictionary where values are based off of a regex - Python

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a dictionary `x = {'123A......': None, '123AA.....': None, '123AB.....': None}`

Assume I also have a list `y = ['123AC.....', '123ABB....', '123ABC....']`

what I want is the following result:

`{'123A......': [123AC....], '123AA.....': ['123AC.....'], '123AB.....': ['123ABB....']}`

I thought something like the following could work,

```
for item in x:
    x[item] = re.findall(r'123[A-Z\.]{7}', ''.join(y))
```

Or something like that. Help appreciated.

Comment: you arent incrementing y in your for loop, so every single x.key will have the exact same value in it

Comment: Ha, just noticed that as well while writing this post. About to amend, well wait a second, y doesn't change. Its just a long string created from a list of strings.

Comment: add a ^ at the begining of your pattern will be safer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want something like this

```
for item in xrange(len(x)):
      x[x.keys()[item]] = re.findall(r'123[A-Z\.]{7}', ''.join(y[item]))
```

this way both x and y are being incremented...

but im pretty sure this can be done even easier with zip

if you have:

```
x = ['123A......', '123AA......', '123AB......'] 
y = ['123AC.....', '123ABB....', '123ABC....']

dict(zip(x,y))
```

it will output

`{'123AB......': '123ABC....', '123A......': '123AC.....', '123AA......': '123ABB....'}`

which i believe would work for you and its waaaaaay easier, because it would preserve the order of the lists ( list item x[0] will be paired with y[0] ) and if you just incr the keys of the dict... weird order stuff happens..... play around with `dict(zip(listA,listB))` and youll see what im talking about

Comment: Okay, this comes closest and I can play with it. Thank you!